# Auto-deleting comments that trigger the blacklist

Tags: comments, spam, akismet

By default, the WP 'blacklist' feature finds comments containing the blacklisted string and moves them to the spam folder. What I am trying to do is change it so that instead of going to spam, the comment goes directly to the trash (or even better isn't stored at all).

In /wp-includes/comment.php around line 700:

```
if ( wp_blacklist_check($comment_author, $comment_author_email, $comment_author_url, $comment_content, $comment_author_IP, $comment_agent) )
    $approved = 'spam';
}
```

I tried modifying the line to `$approved = 'trash';` but I am still getting comments containing blacklisted words being moved to my spam folder. The only comment related plugin I am running in Akismet, is it possible that Akismet is moving the comment to spam before comment.php processes it?

Comment: I can't swear to it, but yes that is a plausible theory.

Comment: @s_ha_dum The Akismet theory? I will try disabling it for a bit and see if there is any change.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected originally, it would appear that Akismet is dealing with the comments before comment.php gets a chance, and thus they avoid the blacklist check entirely. After disabling Akismet the comments are moved to the trash as they should be.

Comment: There are a fair number of [Akismet hooks](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/version/3.5) that you may want to look into.